# If url has index of x or y then do not do the following

Tags: javascript

I think I am having trouble with my syntax on this. I want it to say if the url has indexof 425 or if the url has an indexof 297 do not run the following. This works for doing just one:

```
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('425') === -1){
```

But when I try to add the second indexof it doesnt work, here is what I have tried

```
//attempt 1
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('425') === -1 || document.location.href.indexOf('297') === -1){ 

}
//attempt 2
    if ((document.location.href.indexOf('425')) === -1 || (document.location.href.indexOf('297')) === -1)){ 

}
```

Comment: `=== -1`, with indexOf, means that the searched needle does **NOT** exist in the original string. You probably wanted: `> -1` instead, if you want to perform an action if the url has the searched needle.

Comment: `&&` instead of `||` (AND isntead of OR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want it to say if the url has indexof 425 or if the url has an indexof 297 do not run the following.

Or to put it another way, if the url *doesn't* have 425 **and** *doesn't* have 297, do the following:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('425') === -1 && document.location.href.indexOf('297') === -1){
```

`=== -1` means it wasn't found.

But these days, you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (polyfilling for IE if you need to support IE):

```
if (!document.location.href.includes('425') && !document.location.href.includes('297')){
```

Comment: @Jenny - We all trip over this stuff sometimes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()), because both parts have to be `true`

```
if (
    document.location.href.indexOf('425') === -1 &&
    document.location.href.indexOf('297') === -1
) { 
    // ...
}
```

For more than one value, you could take an array with the unwanted parts and use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking.

```
if ['425', '297'].every(s => !document.location.href.includes(s))) {
    // ...
}
```